# How to test a intellij plugin

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Documentation on Intellij plugin development is scarce. If you have written any Intellij plugin, how did you write tests for plugin? Any pointer to documentation or source code is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Plugins from Community edition (source available [on github](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins)) contain plenty of tests as examples.

Answer (score 6):

Here is some good documentation on the topic: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Testing+IntelliJ+IDEA+Plugins